# bootstrap create textarea and two buttons inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need to create textarea and buttons like below using bootstrap inline form, or any other way below layout, i have tried below code, but it doesn't seem to work

```
<div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="3" style="resize: none" ng-model="formData_EventDetails.serviceNowStr" id="serviceNowStr" readonly placeholder=""></textarea>
                                    <button class="uk-button primary " ng-click="viewServiceNowPopup(formData_EventDetails)" style="display: inline" > &nbsp;View &nbsp;</button>
                                    <button class="uk-button primary " ng-click="openServiceNowPopup(formData_EventDetails)" style="display: inline; margin-top: 5px" > Search </button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "it doesnt seem to work" what issues specifically are you seeing? What have you tried? Have you added any of your own custom CSS?

Answer (score 1):

use bootstrap form horizontal to do this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="3" style="resize: none" ng-model="formData_EventDetails.serviceNowStr" id="serviceNowStr" readonly placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">

      <button class="btn uk-button btn-block btn-default " ng-click="viewServiceNowPopup(formData_EventDetails)"> &nbsp;View &nbsp;</button>
      <button class="btn uk-button btn-block btn-primary " ng-click="openServiceNowPopup(formData_EventDetails)"> Search </button>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

Comment: for proper alignment you have to write some custom css

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control input-sm" rows="3" style="resize: none" ng- 
         model="formData_EventDetails.serviceNowStr" id="serviceNowStr" readonly 
         placeholder=""></textarea>
    </div>
   <div>
       <button class="uk-button primary " ng- 
       click="viewServiceNowPopup(formData_EventDetails)" style="display: inline" > 
       &nbsp;View &nbsp;</button>
       <button class="uk-button primary " ng- 
       click="openServiceNowPopup(formData_EventDetails)" style="display: inline; 
       margin-top: 5px" > Search </button>
   </div>
```